# Defining flag parameters in bash

Tags: linux, bash, shell, centos

I wrote bash script, in which I included some logging, to see what is going on in each step of exectuion.

Now, I can split those logs in debuggin info and user info (that something has completed, etc.). So I'd like to have some flag parameter, like `--verbose`, which I saw in some other bash functions to enable full logging and usage was like:

```
some_function --verbose
```

or

```
some_function -v
```

I call it flag parameters and don't know what's the right name, thus I can't find anything useful.

How to define such parameters for bash script?

Comment: Have a look at [BashFAQ35](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/035)

Comment: @kvantour Thanks, I'll take a look into that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Case suits better for this

```
while [[ "$@" ]]; do
    case "$1" in
        -v|--verbose) verbose="true";;
    esac
    shift
done
```

Same can be done in function, but note that in this case it'll process parameters passed to function `some_function -v`.

```
some_function () {
    while [[ "$@" ]]; do
        case "$1" in
            -v|--verbose) verbose="true";;
        esac
        shift
    done
}
```

Then somewhere in script you can check if `verbose` is set

```
[[ "$verbose" ]] && echo "verbose mode" || echo "silent mode"
```

Answer (score 0):

For now, I used workaround and take it as normal positional parameter (as `$n`). To be exact, I have list of four parameters, so I collect this flag like this:

```
verbose=$4
if [ ! "$verbose" == "--verbose" ]; then
  verbose=""
fi
```

So, if parameter is not matching a flag, then I leave it empty and if I want to use it, I just compare it against empty string.

There's one big disadvantage for me though: it has to be at 4th position in parameters list.